# C fork and pipe printing pid in order

Tags: c, pipe, fork

So I need this program which needs to create argv[1] child using fork() and print what children number are they and what PID do they have in order of its creation.

I have to do that using pipes blocking properties.

Example output:

I am child 1 and my PID is 25853.

I am child 2 and my PID is 25854.

I am child 3 and my PID is 25855.

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't respect the order of children creation.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[80];
    int p[2], i;
    int pid = getpid();
    for (i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
        pipe(p);
        if (fork() == 0) {
            read(p[0], &pid, sizeof(pid)); // It should block here until there's
            // something in the pipe to read
            sprintf(buffer, "I am child %d and my PID is %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
            write(1, &buffer, strlen(buffer));
            close(p[0]);
            close(p[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else { // parent
            close(p[0]);
            write(p[1], &pid, sizeof(pid));
            close(p[1]); // The child is able to read the EOF now.
        }
    }
    while ((waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0)
        ;
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    sprintf(buffer, "I've finished\n");
    write(1, &buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

I feel like I am close but I am not using the pipes block poperties correctly.
I need some advice, thanks.

Comment: The child runs *concurrently* with the parent. In particular, your parent doesn't wait for the child to finish before it `fork()`s the next child, so the order in which the children print to the console is non-deterministic. You should `wait()` *inside* of the `for()`-loop in the parent.

Comment: Yes the point is that it should be concurrently but you have to print the children in order using pipes blockin properties.

Comment: @EOF so I can't use wait on each loop or it won't be concurrent.

Comment: "Concurrent" and "must happen in a specific order" are incompatible requirements. Whoever told you to do this doesn't know what they are doing. If you just don't want to `wait()` specifically, you can create a second `pipe()` that the parent `read()`s from and the child closes so the parent is unblocked. Beware of self-deadlock in this case.

Comment: @EOF but then again this won't be concurrent. This is an exercice I am doing from my university operating system class. 
Reading from a pipe should be blocking the child until it reaches the EOF. Can't I use that property to print them in order?

Comment: I believe you should read my comments again, slowly.

Comment: I did read your comments but you are telling me that it is not possible to do it concurrently. Read this: Write a program that receives as parameter the number of processes that must
Create concurrently. We want child processes to write by their standard output their
PID but we want it to come out in the creation order, so we will have to implement a
Synchronization between them. To implement synchronization between processes and the order of
Writing, ordinary pipes will be used. The father will wait until all his
Children finish and will display the end message of pids.

Comment: I see three possibilities: 1) Whoever gave this assignment was using "concurrently" *very* loosely, and is fine with the parent blocking. 2) Whoever gave this assignment uses a toy OS where child-runs-first is guaranteed. 3) Whoever gave this assignment doesn't have a clue what they are doing. You're welcome to speculate which of these three possibilities applies to your case.

Comment: I agree with EOF, you can't have concurrently and synchronization. This assignment is stupid.

Comment: I think your 1) option is the right one. I've changed my code so I make the parent read from the pipe instead of write and the child write to the pipe instead of read. So the one who is blocking is the parent. Now it works. I think thats the correct answer. Thanks for your time @EOF

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    int const n = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int p[2];
        if (pipe(p) != 0)
            return 1;
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            close(p[1]);
            if (read(p[0], &pid, sizeof pid) != sizeof pid)
              return 1;
            close(p[0]);
            fprintf(stdout, "I am child %d and my PID is %d\n", i + 1, pid);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (pid > 0) {
            close(p[0]);
            if (write(p[1], &pid, sizeof pid) != sizeof pid)
              return 1;
            close(p[1]);
            if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1)
                return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "I've finished\n");
}
```